# Why bootstrap doesn't recognize card?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bootstrapping, web-frontend

I have added bootstrap to my application and when i wrote

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="user in users " style="border: 1px solid black"
         ng-click="goToUserDetails(user.Id)">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">{{user.Email}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">{{user.Name}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">{{user.Password}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-click="delete(user.Id);$event.stopPropagation();">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="gotoAddUser()">Add</button>
</div>
```

It works , but when I want to add a card

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" data-src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't recognize the bootstrap "card" classes (the btn works )
Can someone help me pls?

Comment: do you use bootstrap version 4 style sheet?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no default Card design in Bootstrap 3.3.6 or lower version.**

So now we have only two option for design card.

*The standard way is Upgrade your Bootstrap version like move 3.3.6 or lower to Bootstrap 4. **[Bootstrap 4 Card](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/)***

--- OR ---

*Write your own stylesheet for card design if you want your card design same as well as Bootstrap common design then you can pick that CSS from Bootstrap 4 Card. In this case you can just pick those design which was you actually need for your Card no any other extra CSS so it will not effect your other sections or modules.*